# when trying to add a cognito user getting an error about missing secret

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-cli

I am following this tutorial (so i am a newbe)

i have set up my cognito user pool. (of course if the tutorial is 1 month old it is out of date)

now i am trying to a user via the CLI

```
aws cognito-idp sign-up \
 --region us-east-1 \
 --client-id <CLIENTID> \
 --username randy@mydomain.com \
 --password password
```

And I get the error

An error occurred (NotAuthorizedException) when calling the SignUp operation: Client  is configured for secret but secret was not received

Not sure what to change.

Thanks for any help

Comment: add the parameter --secret-hash as written in the doc  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/sign-up.html#options

To calculate the value you need to do

Base64 ( HMAC_SHA256 ( "User Pool Client Secret Key", "Username" + "Client Id" ) )

You can rely on the script here https://gist.github.com/jaymes-bearden/813a3ae973490b5969c6a3dd208f9f20

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate cognito user Pool, uncheck "create secret" and add allowed domain 'http://localhost' if you are in local or add you domain. This work for me !